# How to fix Read only permission for secondary hard disk drives

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, readonly

I have two storage drive.

1. 128GB SSD [installed Linux Mint]
2. 1 Terabyte HDD [contain few ntfs drives and c drive contain Windows OS]

I disabled fastboot in windows few months ago and then I am not using/booting in windows OS.

Today when I boot in my Linux mint, everything thing is ok except, when I tried to create or delete any file or folder in the drives, it shows error. which is `Error While Creating directory Untitled Folder`.

Some commands I use to fix and fails are:

```
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo chmod 777 /media/shahalom/Movies/
[sudo] password for shahalom:       
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/shahalom/Movies/': Read-only file system
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/shahalom/Movies'
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/shahalom/Works'
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/shahalom/Others'
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo ntfsfix /media/shahalom/Movies
Mounting volume... Error opening '/media/shahalom/Movies': Is a directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening '/media/shahalom/Movies': Is a directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Is a directory
Error opening '/media/shahalom/Movies': Is a directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo umount /media/shahalom/Movies 
[sudo] password for shahalom:       
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo mkdir /media/shahalom/MoviesCollection
shahalom@tutpub:~$ sudo mount -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec,umask=003,blksize=4096 /media/shahalom/Movies /media/shahalom/MoviesCollection
mount: /media/shahalom/MoviesCollection: special device /media/shahalom/Movies does not exist.
shahalom@tutpub:~$ ls -ld /media/shahalom/Movies
ls: cannot access '/media/shahalom/Movies': No such file or directory
shahalom@tutpub:~$ ls -ld /media/shahalom/Works
drwxrwxrwx 1 shahalom shahalom 4096 Apr 23 17:09 /media/shahalom/Works
shahalom@tutpub:~$ ls -ld /media/shahalom/Movies
drwxrwxrwx 1 shahalom shahalom 4096 Apr 23 17:09 /media/shahalom/Movies
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: With `ntfsfix` I believe you need to pass it the `/dev/sdXn` device, rather than the mountpoint.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the relevant mount details, and/or the partition table for the drive?

Comment: `sudo ntfsfix` command not working.

Answer (score 1):

One of the errors indicates the filesystem is mounted in "read only" mode (which may be related to the NTFS format and/or an unclean unmount). There is also mention of "corrupt".

The files will always show the permissions set at the file level (or other value if overridden at the mount level) *even if the filesystem is read-only*.

Take a look at `mount` output to confirm read only state. There should be a message in `dmesg` output mentioning "read only". Some drivers will not allow write if it determines it isn't safe (i.e. corrupt).

It looks like you tried to check/fix the volume. Try running that on the *device* (i.e. partition) when it is unmounted. You may also try performing the suggestion in the error message (i.e. chkdsk).

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here with a dual boot system it can be the case you have SHUTDOWN windows, then restarted your device and gone straight into Linux. This will cause the issue & trying to repair the system will not work.

You need to return to Windows and RESTART the device and then go back into your Linux distro. This is a setting in Windows that "hibernates" the disk drive and places it into a special mode. Linux is told that it can't use it right now for writing.

Once restarted you should find the partition can now be used once more for writing. You can disable this feature, by checking this answer on the partner site:

https://superuser.com/questions/1280156/windows-10-hibernates-instead-of-shutting-down-even-though-fast-startup-is-disa